# reducing invertible matrix in an equation of matrix

Tags: matrices

[image]

Assume that $A^\mathrm{T}A$ is invertible and that $A$ is $3\times 3$, $B$ is $3\times 1$, $\alpha$ is $3\times 1$. How does the expression above reduce?

just to  $A^\mathrm{T}B$ ?

Comment: The information you've given is contradictory: $A$ cannot be both invertible and non-square.

Comment: A $\,3\times 1\,$ matrix (or vector, as you wish to look at it)

Comment: @Hurkyl We can, however, assume that the $3\times 3$ matrix $A^TA$ is invertible (which is what we're inverting anyways). Unless I've forgotten some important theorem.

Comment: If $A$ is rectangular, it doesn't reduce further.

Comment: hmm you guys are right, that makes no sense. If we assume that ATA is invertible, then what does this reduce to?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by reduce. That seems to be as reduced as it gets. You can manipulate it to some other form. For example, $$A^\mathrm{T}A\alpha = A^\mathrm{T}B$$ which is just a standard normal equation. But that's rather trivial.

Comment: @EuYu going from that, can't I take off A transpose from both sides?

Comment: The problem is $A^\mathrm{T}$ is not invertible. There is no general cancellation rule for matrices. $(A^\mathrm{T}A)$ as a whole is the matrix which is invertible. If I'm not mistaken, you're working with least-squares regression or something similar. Normally $\alpha$ is the answer that we want, the equation you posted is typically the final thing we're after.

Comment: @EuYu i think i may have interpreted this question incorrectly, now A is really invertible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is square and $A^tA$ is invertible then of course $A$ is invertible, and your expression simplifies to $A^{-1}B$.

Comment: could you explain the steps for me? thanks

Comment: You know that $(XY)^{-1}=Y^{-1}X^{-1}$? Apply that to $(A^tA)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

The expression itself does not reduce (though there are more complicated methods that are efficient at solving it). I believe your equation may be based on the desire to solve
$$A\vec{\alpha}=B$$
given $A$ and $B$, with $A$ *underdetermined*, meaning it has fewer columns than rows, which is consistent with your problem statement of $5$ rows and $3$ columns for $A$. This equation has no exact solution, thus the next best thing is sought.

As there is no exact solution, consider that a solution that is the "closest" of all possible. With the notion of "close" as the Euclidean distance, it becomes what is called a Least Squares equation. To give you the very abbreviated version of Least Squares, left multiply both sides of the equation to get
$$A^TA\vec{\alpha}=A^TB$$
If you are not yet familiar with Least Squares, for now know that the reason for this is to have something invertible to work with ($A^TA$ will have an inverse) and to keep things in terms of the range of $A$.
Thus, to solve it, again left multiply both sides of the equation to get
$$(A^TA)^{-1}A^TA\vec{\alpha}=(A^TA)^{-1}A^TB$$
which reduces to
$$\vec{\alpha}=(A^TA)^{-1}A^TB$$

This equation then has a solution, and it can be shown to be the closest solution of $\vec{\alpha}$ to the original equation $A\vec{\alpha}=B$

Back again to your original question if it is reduceable; the answer is no-- though there are ways of going about solving this without calculating every middle step as I have shown here, and that would take quite a bit more explaining than I have done thus far.

Comment: thanks for the help. I think i misinterpreted the problem and now I'm going with A as a 3x3 matrix

Comment: The only way for the equation to reduce is if $A$ actually is invertible, then it would reduce to $\alpha=A^{-1}B$